# Creating beautiful and smooth ASP.NET web forms in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, webforms, styles, smoothing

I'm new to ASP.NET programming and I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.
When I create a web form the controls look like [this](http://reza-ameli.azurewebsites.net/WebForm1).

But when the Visual Studio auto-creates web forms, they look smooth and shiny like [this](http://reza-ameli.azurewebsites.net/).

How can I create such smooth/beautiful web forms? What topic should I study?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn the building blocks of awesome looking web-sites, and those blocks are called **JavaScript** and **CSS**, but more importantly **HTML**, and now **HTML5**. Then you can look into *[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)*, *[Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)*, etc... and see/learn how they use those building blocks to render/design awesome looking interfaces that not only look good on desktop web-browsers, but even mobile web-browsers on Android and iPhones. For example, if you utilize Bootstrap to build your ASP.NET application you will not only build for desktop web-browsers but even for mobile platforms, so your work will look great on most mobile/tablet devices.

Then you can kick it up a notch and get fancy with HTML5 and build/tie interactive graphics to your application using something like **[KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/)**. Then go further and learn **[Signal R](http://signalr.net/)** or **[XSockets.NET](http://xsockets.net/)** to build real-time interactive web applications using the power of **WebSockets** and **WebAPI**. With that power you can go even further and add real-time Video and Audio interaction to your web applications using **[WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/)**.

In short, to make things fancy you need to manipulate and utilize the power of the Web-Browser, since your entire user interface components are rendered on the client-side. So, you must learn HTML, JavaScript, and CSS to do magic! The standards of the Web and the power of modern Web-Browsers are growing at exciting rates, and so you must follow if you plan to develop web applications that will be virtually accessed from anywhere!

Since version 2013, Visual Studio has integrated Bootstrap to make forms look shiny and smooth. However, do not expect Visual Studio to keep-up with new User Interface paradigms, components and types of interactions. Yes, Visual Studio helps you design applications using C#/VB.NET etc... But it is up to your creativity and of course customer requirements to build awesome looking work.

Look at where HTML5 is going:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The second link you have ASP.NET is using Twitter BootStrap for its styling

[BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)

This is a front-end framework with a bunch of CSS and Javascript to aid you in creating nice looking websites.  There are other front-end frameworks such as [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

If you want to do it yourself you will need to look into CSS styling rules.  There are many resources for learning how to do your own CSS (some free, some paid).

[Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/)

[CodeCademy](http://www.codecademy.com/)

[Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/)

These should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

you should learn HTML and CSS then use them on your ASP.NET forms.
That particular ASP.NET web form that you posted is using bootstrap as a main css, which you could find [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)